# Clojure prismatic/schema defrecord no enum runtime validation?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, plumatic-schema

When using prismatic/schema, validation of enum on defrecord doesn't work, as shown here:

```
(s/defrecord Action [type :- (s/enum :a :b)])
#'user/strict-map->Action
user> (Action. "3")            ; this should fail
#user.Action{:type "3"}
user> (Action. 1)              ; this should fail
#user.Action{:type 1}
user> (Action. "abc")          ; this should fail
#user.Action{:type "abc"}
```

However, when I change enum to long, it works as expected:

```
(s/defrecord ThisWorks [type :- long])
#'user/strict-map->ThisWorks
user> (ThisWorks. 3)
#user.ThisWorks{:type 3}
user> (ThisWorks. "abc")
ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number  user/eval11888 (form-init4803894880546699153.clj:1)
```

Does anybody know? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you can [switch on and off validation during runtime](http://prismatic.github.io/schema/schema.core.html#var-without-fn-validation) your Records aren't actually checked until you pass them into a function:

```
(s/defrecord Action [type :- (s/enum :a :b)])
(s/defn process-action [x :- Action])
(process-action (Action. "3")) ;; => Exception
```

Regarding `long` magically working. This is just [special clojure behavior due to primitives:](http://clojure.org/datatypes)

> fields can have type hints, and can be primitive
>
> - note that currently a
>     type hint of a non-primitive type will not be used to constrain the
>     field type nor the constructor arg, but will be used to optimize its
>     use in the class methods
> - constraining the field type and constructor
>     arg is planned

```
(s/defrecord PrimitveRec [foo :- long])
(s/defrecord NonPrimitveRec [foo :- String])


(.? NonPrimitveRec :field #"foo" :type)
;=> (java.lang.Object)
(.? PrimitveRec :field #"foo" :type)
;=> (long)
```

Where `.?` is from [Vinyasa](https://github.com/zcaudate/vinyasa).